# How to only allow login for certain users depending on the clientId in Spring OAuth2?

Tags: java, spring, spring-oauth2

I have a working Spring Boot application with OAuth2 support. I have 2 clients, each with their own cliend id:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "my-rest-service";

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
               .withClient("clientOne")
               .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
               .authorities("USER")
               .scopes("read", "write")
               .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
               .secret("123456"))
               .and()
               .withClient("clientTwo")
               .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
               .scopes("read","write")
               .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
               .secret("789654")
               ;

    }
}
```

Further, I have a `User` which has a `Role`. I now want that users that have role ROLE_ONE can only get an authentication token when using `clientOne` and users with ROLE_TWO only can use `clientTwo` to get that.

Where should I add that logic?

Answer (score 0):

What I did for now (but I would love to hear if there are other/better options) is to create a subclass of `ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter` where I copied the code from the `getOAuth2Authentication` method and add my custom logic:

```
...
if (userAuth == null || !userAuth.isAuthenticated()) {
    throw new InvalidGrantException("Could not authenticate user: " + username);
}

// Start of custom code
if( client.getClientId().equals("gamePlayClient")) {
  if( !((CustomUserDetails)userAuth.getPrincipal()).hasPlayerRole()) {
    throw new InsufficientAuthenticationException("Only users with the role 'PLAYER' can log on this client.");
  }
}
// End of custom code

OAuth2Request storedOAuth2Request = getRequestFactory().createOAuth2Request(client, tokenRequest);
return new OAuth2Authentication(storedOAuth2Request, userAuth);
```

This is using version 2.0.9.RELEASE of spring-security-oauth.